# certificate issue in nodejs https request

Tags: node.js, https, ssl-certificate

I have the following error while making an https get request

```
{ Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:802:
at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:864:14) code: 'EPROTO', errno: 'EPROTO', syscall: 'write' }
```

I am trying to make a request to corporate internal resource where proxy is not needed.

```
const request = require('request')
var token= myToken
request({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://myURL',
  data: {
    myData
  },
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer myToken' },
  agentOptions: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
}, function (error, response, body) {
if(error){
  console.log('Error: ', error)
} else {
  console.log(body)
}
})
```

I also have strict-ssl=false in my .npmrc.

What I have notices is that I can make the same call curl with no issues.

```
curl -k1 -XPOST -H "Authorization: Bearer %TOKEN%" "https://%URL% -d @data,json -H "content-type: application/json"
```

-k1 option in curl seems to fix the issue with the certificate.

What am I doing wrong in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in node version 8. I finally found a solution here - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16196

One needs to add the following into her code:

`require("tls").DEFAULT_ECDH_CURVE = "auto"`

Answer (score 1):

```js
request({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://myURL',
  data: {
    myData
  },
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer myToken' },
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
}, function (error, response, body) {
if(error){
  console.log('Error: ', error)
} else {
  console.log(body)
}
});
```

If you don't want the TLS check all over the node project
set process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0;

Comment: both suggestions didn't help - still having handshake failure.

Comment: where did you set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 ?

Comment: first line in the file before `const request = require('request')`